# Difference between return in for loop and outside for loop in a method java

Tags: java

This is a weird question, but im super curious, can anyone explain to me, what is the difference between these 2 same methods that check prime numbers?

```
public boolean isPrime(int numberToCheck){

    for(int divider =2; divider<numberToCheck; divider++){
        if(numberToCheck%divider == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
```

AND

```
    for(int divider =2; divider<numberToCheck; divider++){
        if(numberToCheck%divider != 0){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

As they return 2 difference result, and i still dont really get why,i keep thinking these 2 are the same thing
if the input is 1,101,11,12,200,203,5, the top one returns only 101,11,5, but the other one returns all that was being input

Comment: Try checking by hand.  Do the calculations yourself and ask what is really going on.  To test this by hand you should consider what happens with a wider range of values.  I.e. 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.. etc.  It sounds like a lot of work but it isn't hard, you just need to go through the loop once and work out each value.

Comment: Think of a method as a loop; the moment `return` is called, it `break`s the function so that it finishes executing immediately (recursion would be more like `continue`)

Comment: I actually did, it was because the other method to check the whole array was isPrime instead of !isPrime, because i totally remember putting the exclamation mark, but maybe i typod, been hours going through and through and couldnt find it lol, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part is not correct

```
for(int divider =2; divider<numberToCheck; divider++){
        if(numberToCheck%divider != 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This code will return that the `numberToCheck` is prime after the first `divider` satisfies that `if` expression which is not what you want (for example if `numberToCheck` is 6 and `divider` 4 then `numberToCheck%divider != 0` will be true). 
The first example is correctly checking all the numbers between 2 and the `numberToCheck` and logically returning that the `numberToCheck` is not prime if it is divisible by any `divider`.

Comment: Okay, im really silly, i forgot that the other method that was supposed to check this boolean, was isPrime(number) instead of !isPrime(number), i've been looking back and forth and couldnt find it, until your words made me realize.
thank you!

Comment: @VerzChan no problem! please mark the answer as answered/correct if it helped you